# Extract data from HTML of page contents - Sharepoint / CSOM

Tags: c#, html, .net, wpf, csom

I queried the page contents of my test site as mentioned in the following question:

[Read site page contents in Sharepoint using CSOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48566451/read-site-page-contents-in-sharepoint-using-csom)

```
foreach (var listItem in items)
{
 if (listItem["Title"].ToString() == "My Page")
 {
  var theItem = listItem;
  label2.Content = label2.Content + "\n" + listItem["CanvasContent1"];
 }
}
```

I have a table in my test page and it looks like this:
[image]

The output of the query from C# was:

```
<div><div data-sp-canvascontrol=\"\" data-sp-canvasdataversion=\"1.0\" data-sp-controldata=\"&#123;&quot;controlType&quot;&#58;4,&quot;displayMode&quot;&#58;2,&quot;id&quot;&#58;&quot;1d20c0ad-511c-490f-95d7-acc172475797&quot;,&quot;position&quot;&#58;&#123;&quot;zoneIndex&quot;&#58;1,&quot;sectionIndex&quot;&#58;1,&quot;controlIndex&quot;&#58;1&#125;,&quot;innerHTML&quot;&#58;&quot;&lt;p&gt;Hello Page&lt;/p&gt;\\n\\n&lt;div class=\\&quot;canvasRteResponsiveTable\\&quot;&gt;\\n&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;\\n\\n&lt;div class=\\&quot;canvasRteResponsiveTable\\&quot;&gt;\\n&lt;table style=\\&quot;caret-color&#58;#000000; color&#58;#000000; font-family&#58;-webkit-standard; font-style&#58;normal; font-variant-caps&#58;normal; font-weight&#58;normal; letter-spacing&#58;normal; orphans&#58;auto; text-align&#58;start; text-transform&#58;none; white-space&#58;normal; widows&#58;auto; word-spacing&#58;0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust&#58;auto; -webkit-text-stroke-width&#58;0px; text-decoration&#58;none; border-collapse&
#58;collapse; border&#58;1px solid #000000\\&quot;&gt;\\n\\t&lt;tbody&gt;\\n\\t\\t&lt;tr&gt;\\n\\t\\t\\t&lt;td style=\\&quot;border&#58;1px solid #000000; width&#58;89px\\&quot; valign=\\&quot;top\\&quot;&gt;\\n\\t\\t\\t&lt;p style=\\&quot;margin-left&#58;0px; margin-right&#58;0px\\&quot;&gt;&lt;b&gt;Type&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\\n\\t\\t\\t&lt;/td&gt;\\n\\t\\t\\t&lt;td style=\\&quot;border&#58;1px solid #000000; width&#58;89px\\&quot; valign=\\&quot;top\\&quot;&gt;\\n\\t\\t\\t&lt;p style=\\&quot;margin-left&#58;0px; margin-right&#58;0px\\&quot;&gt;&lt;b&gt;Name&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\\n\\t\\t\\t&lt;/td&gt;\\n\\t\\t&lt;/tr&gt;\\n\\t\\t&lt;tr&gt;\\n\\t\\t\\t&lt;td style=\\&quot;border&#58;1px solid #000000; width&#58;89px\\&quot; valign=\\&quot;top\\&quot;&gt;\\n\\t\\t\\t&lt;p style=\\&quot;margin-left&#58;0px; margin-right&#58;0px\\&quot;&gt;A&lt;/p&gt;\\n\\t\\t\\t&lt;/td&gt;\\n\\t\\t\\t&lt;td style=\\&quot;border&#58;1px solid #000000; width&#58;89px\\&quot; valign=\\&quot;top\\&quot;&gt;\\n\\t\\t\\t&lt;p style=\\&qu
ot;margin-left&#58;0px; margin-right&#58;0px\\&quot;&gt;Carl&lt;/p&gt;\\n\\t\\t\\t&lt;/td&gt;\\n\\t\\t&lt;/tr&gt;\\n\\t\\t&lt;tr&gt;\\n\\t\\t\\t&lt;td style=\\&quot;border&#58;1px solid #000000; width&#58;89px\\&quot; valign=\\&quot;top\\&quot;&gt;\\n\\t\\t\\t&lt;p style=\\&quot;margin-left&#58;0px; margin-right&#58;0px\\&quot;&gt;B&lt;/p&gt;\\n\\t\\t\\t&lt;/td&gt;\\n\\t\\t\\t&lt;td style=\\&quot;border&#58;1px solid #000000; width&#58;89px\\&quot; valign=\\&quot;top\\&quot;&gt;\\n\\t\\t\\t&lt;p style=\\&quot;margin-left&#58;0px; margin-right&#58;0px\\&quot;&gt;Tom&lt;/p&gt;\\n\\t\\t\\t&lt;/td&gt;\\n\\t\\t&lt;/tr&gt;\\n\\t\\t&lt;tr&gt;\\n\\t\\t\\t&lt;td style=\\&quot;border&#58;1px solid #000000; width&#58;89px\\&quot; valign=\\&quot;top\\&quot;&gt;\\n\\t\\t\\t&lt;p style=\\&quot;margin-left&#58;0px; margin-right&#58;0px\\&quot;&gt;C&lt;/p&gt;\\n\\t\\t\\t&lt;/td&gt;\\n\\t\\t\\t&lt;td style=\\&quot;border&#58;1px solid #000000; width&#58;89px\\&quot; valign=\\&quot;top\\&quot;&gt;\\n\\t\\t\\t&lt;p style=\\&quot
;margin-left&#58;0px; margin-right&#58;0px\\&quot;&gt;Ana&lt;/p&gt;\\n\\t\\t\\t&lt;/td&gt;\\n\\t\\t&lt;/tr&gt;\\n\\t&lt;/tbody&gt;\\n&lt;/table&gt;\\n&lt;/div&gt;\\n\\n&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;\\n&lt;/div&gt;\\n\\n&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;\\n&quot;,&quot;editorType&quot;&#58;&quot;CKEditor&quot;,&quot;addedFromPersistedData&quot;&#58;true&#125;\"><div data-sp-rte=\"\"><p>Hello Page</p>\n\n<div class=\"canvasRteResponsiveTable\">\n<p>&#160;</p>\n\n<div class=\"canvasRteResponsiveTable\">\n<table style=\"color&#58;#000000;font-family&#58;-webkit-standard;font-style&#58;normal;font-weight&#58;normal;letter-spacing&#58;normal;text-align&#58;start;text-transform&#58;none;white-space&#58;normal;word-spacing&#58;0px;text-decoration&#58;none;border-collapse&#58;collapse;border&#58;1px solid #000000;\">\n\t<tbody>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td style=\"border&#58;1px solid #000000;width&#58;89px;\" valign=\"top\">\n\t\t\t<p style=\"margin-left&#58;0px;margin-right&#58;0px;\"><b>Type</b></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td style=
\"border&#58;1px solid #000000;width&#58;89px;\" valign=\"top\">\n\t\t\t<p style=\"margin-left&#58;0px;margin-right&#58;0px;\"><b>Name</b></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td style=\"border&#58;1px solid #000000;width&#58;89px;\" valign=\"top\">\n\t\t\t<p style=\"margin-left&#58;0px;margin-right&#58;0px;\">A</p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td style=\"border&#58;1px solid #000000;width&#58;89px;\" valign=\"top\">\n\t\t\t<p style=\"margin-left&#58;0px;margin-right&#58;0px;\">Carl</p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td style=\"border&#58;1px solid #000000;width&#58;89px;\" valign=\"top\">\n\t\t\t<p style=\"margin-left&#58;0px;margin-right&#58;0px;\">B</p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td style=\"border&#58;1px solid #000000;width&#58;89px;\" valign=\"top\">\n\t\t\t<p style=\"margin-left&#58;0px;margin-right&#58;0px;\">Tom</p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td style=\"border&#58;1px solid #000000;width&#58;89px;\" valign=\"top\">\n\t\t\t<p style=\"margin-left&#58;0px;margin-right&#58;0px;\">C</p>
\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td style=\"border&#58;1px solid #000000;width&#58;89px;\" valign=\"top\">\n\t\t\t<p style=\"margin-left&#58;0px;margin-right&#58;0px;\">Ana</p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t</tbody>\n</table>\n</div>\n\n<p>&#160;</p>\n</div>\n\n<p>&#160;</p>\n</div></div></div>
```

Does .NET/CSOM have any way of reading this data more intelligently like mapped objects or some sort of querying within the string so that I can extract the data from the table in the Page?

Basically I just want a better way to extract the data from this variable:

```
listItem["CanvasContent1"]
```

instead of trying to parse a huge html output

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I was looking for suggestions and came across your question. I believe nobody has a right answer. I believe the best we can do is decode the HTML fully and then parse and select the elements.

Decoding it fully requires multiple passes:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string txt = "Your Canvas1Content here"; // In my case this will come from a service
        string decodedHtml = "";
        decodedHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(txt);
        while (txt != decodedHtml)
        {
            txt = decodedHtml;
            decodedHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(txt);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(decodedHtml);
    }
}
```

Afterwards use something like https://html-agility-pack.net to select the nodes and content we want.

I have not yet implemented this, but this is the strategy I will follow in a project I will start soon.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not real clear, but you can access list content from any list, including SitePages using REST web service calls.

You can make SharePoint REST API calls from your JavaScript and use the returned JSON to quickly create a JavaScript object with the data.

```
$.ajax(
{
    "url": "/sites/yourSite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$select=Title",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    "success" = function(data){ ...doSomethingWithTheReturnedData... },
    "error" = function(data){ ...doSomethingWithTheError... }
}
);
```

Comment: I don’t think I can be more clear. REST API is for other technologies that don’t use .NET Framework. I’m using CSOM instead. While I can access List information and anything else very clearly, and easily using CSOM (just like you did in your REST API example), I’m only concerned now about extracting the contents of a particular published page, which are the output of reading the variable listItem["CanvasContent1"] as shown above. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Only way i can imagine is to use the **Jsoup for Java or BeautifulSoup for Python** to parse the HTML contents from the CanvasContent1.

You should be able to navigate to respective div elements and extract which part is required. The **only problem is that every page might not follow similar structure**.

So you need to define a structure and inform the same to the site developers to make it generic.

Comment: The question is about sharepoint, the user is writing javascript code. Using Java or python isn't related to this question